# Automating Data Loading

Tags: data-loader, sandbox, sandbox-refresh

I have seen so many posts regarding this topic but none seem to meet the requirements which I would think are fairly common...

We have several developer orgs and of course one production org, and we refresh roughly every 2 weeks (which is why Full Copy Sandboxes are no good). I would like to implement an automated solution whereby I can set up/map/configure the object model and kick off an automated process that clears the sandbox of data, exports the data from prod, automates the tedious process of using VLOOKUPS to find the new IDs of the newly inserted records, and finally inserts everything into this new org.

Before it is suggested I do not want to build a system based on external IDs as I find this a backward solution, especially on objects such as Leads, Opportunities etc. And as stated above it is not as simple as buying Full Copy Sandbox licenses as we need to refresh more than one per month.

Is there any solution (cloud based or other) where we can set up this configuration, and then simply execute (either command line or UI) to carry out the entire process without manual intervention??

Answer (score 0):

There is an appexchange product called sfxorgdata. Its been helpful to me and is quite cheap.

This solves your problem of not having external id